# Interstellar and Newton's Third Law

Tags: interstellar

[In the scene](https://youtu.be/_GdEsdEfZvc) where Cooper ejects himself into space, towards Gargantua, he quotes Newton's Third Law of Motion:

> "You have to leave something behind to go forward"

We all know that that Law states:

> "for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction"

Well the question is that he's basically dumping fuel to get a slingshot to go into Gargantua, but instead I believe that rather than referring to technical details, Cooper is actually hitting our emotional nerves - in his last chance to save earth. I believe that that's why he said the quote as he knew he was going  for an everlasting sacrifice for humanity.

What does he actually mean in the scene?

Comment: I've tidied up your question, I hope I haven't deviated from what you were implying. I've also removed the last part which is actually a new question (We only accept one question per post, as it becomes 'too-broad').

Comment: Hmmm, the exact same (rambling) question was also posted on https://movies.stackexchange.com/ a couple of days ago. Seems to have disappeared there.

Comment: No answers. Diverse opinions. Either people don't get the scene or just they throwing judgments.

Comment: Probably disappeared via deletion, it's a bad question for SE regardless of where.

Comment: @Nij why its seems so bad? Please clarify so i will get idea whats the right things to ask.thanks

Comment: You're asking a question that cannot be answered by objective expertise. *"What does it actually mean?"* requires subjective interpretation of a creative work - there is possibly nothing that would get more opinion-based in the entire network.

Comment: @Nij ok. Seems my platform wrong. Yeah its not straightforward to get answer but was opinion based.

Comment: As it's currently worded (edited), it's not **that** bad a question, IMHO. I think if you are looking for an analysis of the scene and the quote in context from a literary standpoint, then you haven't quite worded it that way, but that's how I have answered it. From that point of view, I think the intent of the scene and the quote is pretty clear once you think of it as a literary device, and therefore the question is answerable and not a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yup as its very narrow line between opinion and straightforward answer as its based on critical thinking and emotional part but SE expertise want to talk more on facts and rational answer, but im thinking the same as per your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The writers, via the character, are using Newton's third law as a metaphor for emotional and psychological progress.

In rocketry, Newton's third law applies in the sense that the momentum of the material ejected from the back of the rocket imparts equal momentum in the opposite direction to the rocket itself. So the burned fuel is "left behind" (ejected at high speed, really) so the rocket can move forward.

The fact that Cooper paraphrases Newton so heavily (merely leaving something behind with no motion imparted to it will not actually generate forward momentum) tells us that he's not literally talking about rocketry or momentum or even physics at all. He's drawing a parallel, and suggesting that in order for a person to move forward emotionally, that person must give up emotional ties to something holding them back. In this case, he himself is what he is suggesting must be let go of emotionally, with the belief that ties to him and his life are holding the characters back.

He's also saying that he must let go of his love for life and move forward in his journey through his existence, even if it means the end of his existence. The whole notion is a good candidate for being the theme of the movie in general.

Comment: Thanks, you portrayed, defined very well.

Answer (score 0):

**What does he actually mean in the scene?**

Well, best shot is to ask the writers (J. & C. Nolan) and director (C. Nolan), because only they know what was the idea behind these lines, formed into final state in production. Though, we can do educated guess, which I think will qualify "close enough".

That is trivial, the scene is absolutely building up tension, which will give more weight for any dramatic line coming. The discussion is also a key moment of the movie about the protagonist, parting from the rest of the support characters. The use of now really dramatic, rephrased words of this physics law **puts the moment a grade higher. I believe, this is the only and full purpose of using the line here**, and there will not be more depth to uncover - in the aspect of intentional meanings.

However, if someone will really go forward and ask the writers, I think they will theorize up some more mystic explanation, since the question is going after what they intended in the given time and effort for this scene, and creators rarely value to have their work seen plain and simple :) and a Q&A like that is a chance to further enhance the opinion of the people.

Comment: Now that's constructive reply i am waiting about. Thanks